# Are questions about missing users on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Looking through the list of users I recognized that one high ranking member of TSE is missing completely on SE since August 16th, 2016.

Could we ask here on meta if someone knows something about a missing user in general?

Comment: @pnuts he's not a travel person though, right?

Comment: He is accruing more passive rep than most active people get! Incredible.

Comment: Fear not! I'm alive. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> Meta Travel Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Travel Stack Exchange rather than discussing traveling itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...
>
> - ...**Travel Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other** about
>     Travel Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work,
>     or about policies and community decisions)
> - ...**Travel Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company** (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and
> - ...**Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community** (soliciting
>     feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect
>     the whole network)
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before, and
>   avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with Travel Stack
>   Exchange or the Stack Exchange network. This is not a random
>   discussion area; rather, it's a place for improving our community and
>   website, together.

IMO *asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions* does not cover asking about "missing users" in general, though does include asking about bans imposed by mods acting on behalf of the Community. However since it is policy to discuss the latter as little as possible asking about bans may not achieve any comprehensive answers.